# Slow Magento Order processing due to opcheckout.js line 957

Tags: arrays, performance, magento-1.9

We have a Magento site. When the user clicks to submit their order there is a 30-40 second delay before the order is processed.

It seems to have to do with the way the site is processing opcheckout.js

Here is a screenshot of the waterfall showing the delay:

http://icecream.me/f80e85dabece0e1989ee154e29e1ba1f

Does anyone have ideas of what we should be looking for to fix this?

Thanks in advance